# i keep having an error in the {{ form|crispy }} line how to fix it?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

```
`{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
                  Join today
                </legend>
                {{ form|crispy}}
            </fieldset>
            <div class ="form-group">
                <button class="btn-outline-info " type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </div>

        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">Already have an account<a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign in</a>
            </small>
        </div>

    </div>
           
{% endblock content %}`
```

i tried the   {% crispy form %} as well but still there is an error
i did all these steps :
Check Crispy Forms Configuration:

Ensure that you have properly configured django-crispy-forms to use Bootstrap. In your project's settings.py, make sure you have set the CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK to 'bootstrap4' if you are using Bootstrap 4:

python
Copy code
`CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'`
Check Installed Apps:

Verify that 'crispy_forms' is included in your INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py. It should look like this:

python
Copy code
`INSTALLED_APPS = [ # ... 'crispy_forms', # ... ]` Check Template Load Tags:

Ensure that you have loaded the crispy_forms_tags at the top of your template file:

html
Copy code
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
Correct Template Tag Usage:

Double-check that you are using the {{ form|crispy }} filter correctly to render your form with Crispy Forms:

html
Copy code
{{ form|crispy }}
Template Location:

Confirm that the 'uni_form.html' template is not referenced explicitly in your 'register.html' template or any other templates. If it is, remove such references.
Clean Cache and Restart Server:

Sometimes, template-related issues can be cached. Try clearing your Django template cache by deleting the contents of the cache directory (usually located in the 'django_extensions' directory) and then restart your development server.

Comment: Show your settings.py file.

Comment: And share your installed pip packages. Especially the crispy-related ones.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.